# Apply Containment to Clone JQuery

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I want to apply containment to the clone of an image when it is dragged from one `div` to another (keeping the clone draggable).

The problem is when an image is dragged and dropped to the certain `div` the Clone becomes un-draggable, inorder to make it draggable i have called `.draggable` function but by calling that it loses its containment attribute and become draggable everywhere. I have tried my best to find a solution for it but I can't find anything.

```
   $(function() {


    $(".Move-Icon-Class").draggable(
    {

    containment: '#screen',
    helper:'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    scroll: false,
    collision: 'fit flip',

    }
    );

    $("#screen").droppable({
      accept: '.Move-Icon-Class',
      activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
      hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        dropped = true;
        $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
        ui.helper.appendTo(this).draggable(); // this is where i want to apply containment
      }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `draggable` within `drop`, you will want to set the `containment` option at that time.

```
ui.helper.appendTo(this).draggable({
  containment: '#screen'
});
```

This will set the containment again.

Comment: It is very Strange i also tired that, but it didn't worked. But now it does, i wonder what i have typed wrong.

Many Thanks mate!